# Convert linq query into lambda query with joins

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am new to lambda. how can i write below code using lambda.
thanks

```
User user1 = (from u in db.Users
                                  join h in db.HCM_SMS_ROLE_MAPPINGs
                                  on u.roleID equals h.SMS_Role_ID
                                  where (u.Employee_Code == employeeCode && u.isDeleted == false && h.Is_Active_App == true)
                                  select u).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: http://lq2m.azurewebsites.net

Comment: I think you meant from query syntax to method syntax because both would be considered `LINQ`

Comment: can you share your model classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
db.Users.Join(db.HCM_SMS_ROLE_MAPPINGs, u => u.roleID, h => h.SMS_Role_ID, (u, h) => new
{
u, h
}
).Where(x=> x.u.Employee_Code == employeeCode && x.u.isDeleted == false && x.h.Is_Active_App == true).Select(x=> x.u).Distinct().FirstOrDefault()
```

Clean and Simple! Hope it helps

Comment: that's the correct lambda version for the query syntax in the question, though please remember for Distinct to work on the complete object either pass `IEqualityComparer` or implement `IEquatable`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj can you please suggest an edit explaining that? I don't understand how to do it correctly.

Comment: that's the overload of the Disntinct, which can be supplied an `IEqualityComparer`, or the class needs to implement `IEquatable`, so when class doesn't implement `IEquatable`, then we go for the external `IEqualityComparer`, these are points which helps in resolving issues in a class object doing the equality comparison else it goes for the reference comparison instead of the value / property comparison which we are generally expecting for the primitive types

Comment: @MrinalKamboj is it like I make a class inherit from `IEqualityComparer` of type `ClassToBeCompared` and add a method Equals to it?  like this:  `class Compare : IEqualityComparer<ClassToBeCompared>
    {
public bool Equals(ClassToBeCompared x, ClassToBeCompared y)
{
    return x.Numf == y.Numf;
}
}`

Comment: yes you can use `IEqualityComparer` derived class if the class doesn't implement `IEquatable` by default, idea is to do value comparison for the reference types, which might otherwise check the reference equality by default

Comment: @MrinalKamboj got it, Thanks for sharing the valuable information. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My method is to right click the lightbulb in the left hand side bar and select 'Convert LINQ to method chain', which gives this:

```
User user1 = (db.Users
                .Join(db.HCM_SMS_ROLE_MAPPINGs, 
                   u => u.roleID, 
                   h => h.SMS_Role_ID, 
                   (u, h) => new { u, h })
                .Where(@t => (u.Employee_Code == employeeCode && u.isDeleted == false && h.Is_Active_App == true))
                .Select(@t => u))
                .Distinct()
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I think this is a Resharper feature.

Comment: great though you may add an explanation, not everyone would have the Resharper